# Compass in maps and app always wrong

Tags: iphone, google-maps, compass

When I use the direction in maps the direction is almost always ~90° off, occasionally it will be 135-180° wrong but mostly it looks like I'm travelling sideways. The phone is flat. 
Is there something wrong with the hardware? Or can I manually calibrate it (like tell it to offset by 90°)? Or tell it to ignore the compass and just use the direction of travel.

Also the compass app gives the wrong direction but it doesn't even match the incorrect direction in maps.

For example I was travelling along this road, away from the motorway.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, what you will need to do is re-calibrate the compass multiple times and it will get closer and closer with each calibration.

Make sure you are calibrating in the correct way, most people I have seen do it wrong, and it is not very clear from the diagram on the phone. There is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytBSKfQNvI4&feature=player_embedded) which will show you how

Answer (score 0):

I know this old but I came here from google after having the same problem on iOS 10 and my 6s.   I tried all the suggestions to recalibrate by toggling location services, rebooting, etc, and nothing worked.  Finally realized that it was all because my wallet case for the phone has a little magnetic tab on it.  So if you're having that problem, make sure you don't have a magnet on your case or nearby.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I came to the conclusion that the error was due to the magnet of my iPhone's wallet case.

Removing the case with the magnet is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem in 2021. Both with my iPhone and Apple Watch. Finally found out that I was using magnetic north instead of **true north**. [Switching it to True North is recommended](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/04/28/how-to-iphone-compass-apple-maps-navigation/). It is now much more accurate.